# iOS widget not working on few iPhone5S

Tags: ios, widget, ios-app-extension, ios8-today-widget

We are facing very weird issue. We have implemented the iOS8 widget and its working fine with iPhone5, iPhone5C, iPhone6 but it's not working with iPhone5S. Sometime its working with iOS 8.2 and sometimes it suddenly stop working. I am not able to figure out the exact cause.

Widget is showing only app icon & app name and doesn't show any widget content.

We set the architecture to arm64 as well but doesn't help. 
Please let us know if you have any idea to resolve this issue or some faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an extension takes too much time to load at start then it won't show up and would show as crash in device logs. Check device logs.

Also recheck if you are setting the widget height properly.